# User based data access

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, authentication

Am trying to find the best way to implement a user based data access. For example, imagine that we have a company with a CEO and different department heads. A database contains the financials of each department, the CEO can view the financials of all the departments, while each head of departments can only view the data related to his/her department.

The database I am using is PostgreSQL which doesn't yet implement row level access rules.

I was wondering if there is a known paradigm that can be used implement this. I looked at the RBAC, but this seems way too complicated for my needs.

Any advice/remarks?

Elie

Comment: Probably a better fit on dba.SE.

Answer (score 2):

Imo, access-control is much more convenient to implement at the application level.

For all its merits, database-level (even with row-level) access control won't allow you to easily manage thorny use-cases such as: "allow the manager's secretary masquerade as the manager for this subset of tasks while he takes a week off next month." Stick to using it to prevent the app's database user from breaking the data.

At the application level, look into a bit deeper in RBAC and ACL. There are some good implementations around, complete with schema. For instance:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl.html

Whichever approach you pick, I think the key is to have it so that you can plug application logic in there using some variation of the Observer Pattern (event, filter, plugin hook, whatever it's called in your favorite framework). This will allow you to manage the thornier cases using callbacks instead of a monstrosity of a schema.

Some (colorful and controversial) speakers take it a step further: http://vimeo.com/2723800

Answer (score 0):

This is a complex topic.  I don't uncritically endorse Denis's recommendation for application-based access control because while it is often the right place to put it, it isn't always.  Once you go with an application-based solution you are stuck with all requests going through the application.  The question is whether that is the tradeoff you want to make or whether you want the rules to be preserved when going through things otherwise.

PostgreSQL doesn't have simple row-based access control, but there are sufficient tools to make something work if you need to.  This is not simple, but it has the advantage of being application-neutral.  A complete solution is beyond the scope of any single post but here are the potential pieces that come to mind:

1. security barrier views (you can use triggers to manage updates)
2. pg_has_role()

Now, what this has in common with Denis's answer above is that you aren't just implementing this on the tables but in a data processing layer.  The question is which side of the database connection that layer is placed, nothing more.  The needs there are determined by the question of where you want to enforce all access.